If you're not powerful enough to add a block to the block chain, is there any financial incentive to run a full node?
Since there are many powerful computers now being used to compete in proof-of-work, a small operator has no chance of adding a block to the blopck chain. I appreciate the importance of having many full nodes to validate and maintain the integrity of a decentralized network. But is it true that there is no financial incentive for running a full node?


is it true that there is no financial incentive for running a full node?

Yes.
No direct financial incentive.
If you own bitcoin, you do have an interest in sustaining the bitcoin network.
